# iPhone - handling two XIBs for two orientations

Tags: iphone

I have an app I would have two XIBs: one for portrait and one for landscape.

I am not sure what is the best way to do that, but my guess is...
I design both XIBs on Interface Builder and link them to UIViewControllers and create another class to manage them. But what class? UINavigationController?

How do I switch with animation between the two XIBs?

Do I have to declare both and have the switching method on the app delegate?

Can you guys point to some tutorial or example?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone/ipad orientation handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815802/iphone-ipad-orientation-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Google Books for Beginning iPhone 3 Development: Exploring the IPhone SDK By Dave Mark, Jeff LaMarche. Chapter 5 provides great information on supporting landscape and portrait mode.