# How to get orientation in iPad programmatically?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, ipad

I am making an iPad app. In this app I am using table view in `DetailViewController` which I have added a logic that my table cell will adjust its height based on the content.The content is made as a label and then added into table view cell. I have set the width of label as 680px. It worked right in portrait mode but i have to set 615px in landscape mode.

How I can get that in which orientation my iPad is and then using if statement to set the label width.

I used `CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);` to get the width in `viewWillAppear`.But if my app runs in portrait then it will give width in portrait but when i go to landscape mode i am getting no width. Please tell where i can put the above line to get width in both portrait and landscape on orientation at any time or if there's any other mean for getting this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone/ipad orientation handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815802/iphone-ipad-orientation-handling)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        titleImageView.center = CGPointMake(235.0f, 42.0f);
        subtitleImageView.center = CGPointMake(355.0f, 70.0f);
        ...
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        titleImageView.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 52.0f);
        subtitleImageView.center = CGPointMake(275.0f, 80.0f);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `statusBarOrientation`, since sometimes the device orientation can change but the status bar will not (such as when the device may be flat on a desk).

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
{
    adjWidth = 480.0;
}
else
{
    adjWidth = 320.0;
}
```