# How to handle UI components when device orientation for iPhone/iPad changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uideviceorientation

I have several components on my UIView like textfields, labels, tables, buttons. I want to handle device orientation changes. 
How to make these components arrange at right place automatically? Or do I need to re-frame them?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Dup of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815802/iphone-ipad-orientation-handling

Comment: 2 Options: (1) Resetting frames of each and every components or (2) having XIBs for different orientations. Very common issue. You would have found solution by googling it. cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You may use Autosizing option for the orientation changes.No need to write even a single line of code.

Comment: hm..its just adjusting the components in the interface builder.No code is required.Say,if u have a label in the IB,select the label and click on size inspector.You can see the autoresizing graph there.Try removing these red lines and check whether the orientation is correct on landscape and portrait mode.If it is not correct try changing/removing any other red lines.It will be in correct position atleast at one position.You have to build and check each time for getting the correct result.Hope u understood.If any querries let me know

Comment: @Mobility with ur pleasure..:)

Comment: Hi @alpz, What if i am not using interface builder .. do i need to calculate dimensions again and loadView ?

Comment: @Sakti if u r not on IB,you can follow the method posted as answer just below this.You have to check the orientation and give the dimensions of the components manually.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    // set you subviews,Label button frame here for landscape mode,,
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    // set you subviews,Label button frame here for portrait-mode,
}
}
```

//Don't forget to add this `Delegate` Method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{


    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
       // portrait Arrangement
    }       
    else 
    { 
        // Landscape Arrangement
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```