# Best way to handle device orientation iPad

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone/ipad orientation handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815802/iphone-ipad-orientation-handling)

i beg your pardon. i am very new in iOS. would you please tell me the best way to handle device orientation.

I mean replacing subview at the time of orientation changed.

Comment: any specific reason for down vote...if anything wrong there please edit the question or tell me what i have done wrong there so that i can keep in mind next time...i wouldn't mind getting down voting...but i need to know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do some RnD before posting any question. This is the best site for any platform specially for iOS. This question is already been answered. As you are a new bee its okay.

Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815802/iphone-ipad-orientation-handling), you can try this. Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: thanks. i understand...sorry for bothering...i will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 6 new methods are here to let you know about `Device Orientation`

This method is for support device orientation `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` means it would support all 4 orientations.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

This method would be call when your device would change current orientation.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   if(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])                  
   {
      NSLog(@"Portrait Mode");
   }
   else if(UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
   {
      NSLog(@"Portrait UpSideDown Mode");
   }
   else if(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
   {
      NSLog(@"Landscape Left Mode");
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"Landscape Right Mode");
   }
   return YES;
}
```

See this link for more about `UIInterfaceOrientation` in IOS 6 [Interface Orientation in IOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow%3a)